# Simulate drag in force layout

Tags: javascript, d3.js, force-layout

If you look at this example http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/3750558

You can drag a node and drop it, as the node's position changes, the corresponding link is stretched/compressed. I'd like to achieve the same thing but programmatically.

So, basically, I'd like to animate the node from it's corresponding position to a target position `(x, y)`. If I apply `d3.transition` on the node, only the node changes it's position but then I'll have to animate the link as well, and these animations are not in sync!

So, what's the best way to simulate the drag?

Comment: I've asked this question here : ^^^^^  i think its what you're after ?

Comment: exact duplicate! How did you find this question? I did search alot but couldn't come across, thanks anyway :)

Comment: yeah i asked the question myself, maybe i should rename it so it's found easier ...